# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MyRepository in test cases nodejs

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

This is my repository

```
@Injectable()
export class MyRepository extends Repository<MyData> {
  constructor(private dataSource: DataSource) {
    super(MyData, dataSource.createEntityManager());
  }
}
```

and spec file's before each

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [MyController],
      providers: [
        MyService,
        MyRepository ,

      ],
    }).compile();
```

but i am facing this

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MyRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument DataSource at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a mock for the `DataSource` provider. Honestly, you *should* be mocking anything that gets injected into the class you are testing, rather than adding it to the testing module for unit testing.

```js
{
  provide: DataSource,
  useValue: {
    createEntityManager: jest.fn(),
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please help on this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76852575/cannot-read-property-getrequestid-of-undefined-nestjs-test-cases-nodejs