# Cannot read property 'getRequestId' of undefined nestjs test cases nodejs

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I have a logger service

```
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RequestIdProvider } from "src/common/services/request-id.provider";

export class AppLogger extends Logger {

  constructor(private readonly requestIdProvider: RequestIdProvider) {
    super();
  }

  private formatMessage(message: any[], requestId: string): string {
    const logMessage = message.map((msg) => (typeof msg === 'string' ? msg : JSON.stringify(msg))).join(' ');
    return `[Request ID: ${requestId}] ${logMessage}`;
  }

  log(...messages: any[]) {
    const requestId = this.requestIdProvider.getRequestId();
    super.log(this.formatMessage(messages, requestId));
  }
```

and here is the request-id provider

```
import { REQUEST } from "@nestjs/core";
import { Injectable, Scope, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class RequestIdProvider {
  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request) { }

  getRequestId(): string {
    return this.request.requestId;
  }
}
```

and in my test case

```
describe('MyController', () => {
  let controller: MyController;
  let service: myService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [RolesController],
      providers: [
        MyService, AppLogger, RequestIdProvider,
```

but i am facing this

```
  ● MyController › update › should update a role

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRequestId' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create appLogger instance

```
const mockRequestIdProvider: any = {
      getRequestId: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('test-request-id'), // Provide a mock implementation
    };
appLogger = new AppLogger(mockRequestIdProvider);
```

and then in providers

```
{ provide: AppLogger, useValue: appLogger },
```